# Setting axis limits (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) from external .dat file

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, external-files, import, axis

I am importing the data for my plot from a .dat file produced in matlab. I would also like to set axis limits from a `.dat` file. Is there a way to set xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax from a table in a `.dat` matrix (like the data plotted later)? How I'm currently setting the axis limits is shown below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf,pgffor}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\def\names{{Folder1/}{Folder2/}{Folder3/}}

\foreach \x in \names{
\graphicspath{ \x {Icons/}}  

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 

    \begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits = false,
    hide axis,
    ]
        \addplot graphics [
            xmin=-80.5430, xmax=-80.5150,
            ymin=43.4580, ymax=43.4740,
            ]{ov2.png};
        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark=text,
            text mark={\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{icon.png}}
        ]
        table [search path={\x}]{overnight.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Rather than define the xmin xmax in the code I would like to have them defined in a `.dat` file containing the axis limits (they are not a function of the data being plotted they are the GPS coordinates of the corners of the image `ov2.png` being overlaid)

Comment: Could you perhaps consider making the question more precise? Which information is in the `.dat` file? The actual `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin` and `ymax`, or a set of `x` and `y` values from which one has to determine these values?

Comment: It appears you are using a separate file for each \addplot, where the columns are titled x and y.  Once can read such a file using \pgfplotstable and extract individual numbers using \pgfplotstablegetelem.  [xmin={\xmin}]

Comment: Can you please provide code we can compile? Your code right now is just a snippet of a document, lacking lots of essential parts and reliant on external files we don't have. So we can't play around with it to try anything out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, you can use `\pgfplotstablegetelem` to access an individual element of a data file. This requires you to know the row and the column of it. The value is returned in `\pgfplotsretval`. Columns can be referenced by name and rows by their index, starting with 0.

It is also possible to loop through a column and do something with each value, using `\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement`. This can, for example, be used to find the minimum, maximum or average.

It's a good idea, to write a few macros for this, especially in the second case. The following code shows some examples:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
x y
-1.5 27.3
-1.0 24.8
-0.5 22.1
0.0 30.7
0.5 11.3
1.0 15.9
1.5 20.4
2.0 21.8
2.5 22.8
\end{filecontents}

% read the table
\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\datatable

% get specific element and store it in a macro
% #1: table
% #2: row
% #3: column (name or [index]<index>)
% #4: macro for value
\newcommand*{\GetElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}

% get the first element of a column and store it in a macro
% #1: table
% #2: column (name or [index]<index>)
% #3: macro for value
\newcommand*{\GetFirstElement}[3]{%
    \GetElement{#1}{0}{#2}{#3}%
}

% get the last element of a column and store it in a macro
% #1: table
% #2: column (name or [index]<index>)
% #3: macro for value
\newcommand*{\GetLastElement}[3]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lastrowidx{int(\pgfplotsretval - 1)}%
    \GetElement{#1}{\lastrowidx}{#2}{#3}%
}

% get maximum and minimum value of a column and store them in macros
% #1: table
% #2: column
% #3: macro for max
% #4: macro for min
\newcommand*{\GetMinMax}[4]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro#3{-16383}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro#4{16383}%
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#2}\of{#1}\as\cellValue{%
        \ifx\cellValue\@empty\else
            \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{max(#3,\cellValue)}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{#4}{min(#4,\cellValue)}%
        \fi
    }
}

% get average of column and store it in a macro
% #1: table
% #2: column
% #3: macro for average
\newcommand*{\GetAverage}[3]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}%
    \let\rownumber\pgfplotsretval
    \def#3{0}%
    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{#2}\of{#1}\as\cellValue{%
        \ifx\cellValue\@empty
            % don't count emplty cells
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\rownumber}{\rownumber - 1}%
        \else
            \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{#3 + \cellValue}%
        \fi
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{#3 / \rownumber}%
}


\GetMinMax{\datatable}{x}{\dataxmax}{\dataxmin}
\GetMinMax{\datatable}{y}{\dataymax}{\dataymin}
\GetElement{\datatable}{5}{y}{\value}
\GetFirstElement{\datatable}{y}{\first}
\GetLastElement{\datatable}{y}{\last}
\GetMinMax{\datatable}{x}{\dataxmax}{\dataxmin}
\GetMinMax{\datatable}{y}{\dataymax}{\dataymin}
\GetAverage{\datatable}{y}{\average}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xlabel=$x$-label,
    ylabel=$y$-label,
    xmin=\dataxmin, xmax=\dataxmax,
    ymin=\dataymin, ymax=\dataymax,
]
\addplot table[x=x,y=y] {\datatable};
\draw[red] (axis cs:\dataxmin,\value) -- node[pos=0.35, above] {\value} (axis cs:\dataxmax,\value);
\draw[green] (axis cs:\dataxmin,\first) -- node[pos=0.07, above] {\first} node[pos=0.93, above] {\last} (axis cs:\dataxmax,\last);
\draw[cyan] (axis cs:\dataxmin,\average) -- node[pos=0.25, below] {average $=$ \average} (axis cs:\dataxmax,\average);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some commands are very similar to what one finds [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107364/121799) (and also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442061/121799))...