# Normalize by the i-th value of a series

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a `data.csv` that looks like (note that there's no header)

`0.0, 0.8, 0.5
0.5, 0.4, 0.7
1.0, 1.0, 0.4`

that I want to plot using `pgfplots`.  I want the plot to rescale the values in the 2nd (index = 1) and 3rd (index = 2) columns by the value in the first row, so that the values become

`0.0, 1.0, 1.0
0.5, 0.5, 1.4
1.0, 1.25, 0.8`

on the plot.  Currently, the way I do this is setting `y expr = \thisrowno{1}/0.8` when plotting the 2nd column on the y axis.  However, the csv file changes often and having to hard-code this is costly.  I also don't have control over the csv generation, so rescaling at data-generation is not feasible.  I could easily process this in some other language prior to plotting, but I'm interested to know whether this can be done within `pgfplots`, and potentially using an arbitrary row (1st and last are obviously the most valuable)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0.0, 0.8, 0.5
0.5, 0.4, 0.7
1.0, 1.0, 0.4
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [
       x index = {0}, y index = {1},
       y expr  = \thisrowno{1}/0.8,
       col sep = comma,
      ] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just read the values in advance and then use them. This code is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107364/121799), [that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442061/121799). These answers have also been [used here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442767/121799), I think.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0.0, 0.8, 0.5
0.5, 0.4, 0.7
1.0, 1.0, 0.4
\end{filecontents}
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{[index]#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}
\newcommand{\Normalization}[2]{\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{0}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\NormalizationFromLastRow}[2]{
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownumber}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\rownumber}{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[header=false,col sep=comma]{data.csv}\datatable
\Normalization{1}{\mynorm}
\NormalizationFromLastRow{1}{\mylastnorm}
\typeout{\mylastnorm}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [
       x index = {0}, y index = {1},
       y expr  = \thisrowno{1}/\mynorm,
       col sep = comma,
      ] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the last row?

Comment: @Shffl I added a command that gets the normalization from the last row. It is sometimes confusing that the numbering starts at 0, at least for me...