# appearance of regression line

Tags: pgfplots

Can anyone explain the uneven appearance of the regression line in this plot?

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
a,b
5,14
4,13
6,11
8,12
8,10
5,9
3,12
}\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks] table [x=a, y=b] {\data};
\addplot [dashdotted] table [x=a, y={create col/linear regression={y=b}}] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pgfplots decomposes the regression line into small overlapping segments. Luckily it computes the parameters of the regression line and stores them into `\pgfplotstableregressionb` and `\pgfplotstableregressiona`, which allows one to draw the regression line as an ordinary single-stroke plot.

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
a,b
5,14
4,13
6,11
8,12
8,10
5,9
3,12
}\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks] table [x=a, y=b] {\data};
\addplot [draw=none] table [x=a, 
y={create col/linear regression={y=b}}] {\data};
\addplot[dashdotted,domain=3:8] {\pgfplotstableregressionb+\pgfplotstableregressiona*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not like the fact that the domain `3:8` is hard coded, you could do

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
a,b
5,14
4,13
6,11
8,12
8,10
5,9
3,12
}\data
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445369/121799
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}
\newcommand{\GetDomain}[3]{
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\data}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownumber}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\ReadOutElement{\data}{0}{#1}{\tmp}
\let#2\tmp
\let#3\tmp
\foreach \XX in {1,...,\rownumber}
{
\ReadOutElement{\data}{\XX}{#1}{\tmp}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#2}{min(#2,\tmp)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{max(#3,\tmp)}
\xdef#2{#2}
\xdef#3{#3}
}
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks] table [x=a, y=b] {\data};
\addplot [draw=none] table [x=a, 
y={create col/linear regression={y=b}}] {\data};
\GetDomain{a}{\amin}{\amax}
\addplot[dashdotted,domain=\amin:\amax] {\pgfplotstableregressionb+\pgfplotstableregressiona*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does pgfplots do that? Given the result this seems like a clear bug. And linear regression never requires more than a single line segment, only nonlinear/local regression does.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I wouldn't call it a bug. I think it was just not foreseen that someone wants to draw a dash-dotted line in a data set in which the x coordinates do not appear in an ascending order.

Comment: @marmot - Kind of sounds like a bug to me

Comment: @Dason Sure, this is something one may argue about. My attitude it that pgfplots is a really great tool, which allows one to do many nice things, and it provides means to draw the dash-dotted line with little effort. IMHO it would be a bug if the line was off (incorrect slope or sth like this), but this is not the case. All one has to do is to work a tiny bit harder to get the result. But of course it is a matter of taste which point of view one finds more convincing.

Comment: It's not really for me to say if it's a bug or not, but just to note: the effect is apparent on other types of line (dotted, dashed), not just dash-dotted.

Comment: @GarethWalker I agree. One more addition to your list: lines with nontrivial opacity. ;-)