# How to print a Answer Key in a particular case of multiple-choice-Exam that randomizes the order of enumerate items? (See more.)

Tags: enumerate

The code below generates several exams with the name of the students. The code also randomizes the order of enumerate items.

I’d like **to print at the end of this document (in an additional page) each student’s name and the corresponding Answer Key (question number + correct letter)**. Is it possible? It is possible to label in some way the items corresponding to the correct answers and print them at the end?

HOW COULD I DO THIS?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=6mm,includehead,left=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float} % pct para crrg fig. com 2 ou + colunas.
\usepackage{multicol} % pct para crrg 2 ou + colunas
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath}



\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

% code for generating a random permutation
\newcounter{randomListLength}%   current length of our random list
\newcounter{randomListPosition}% current list index
\newcounter{newRandomListElementPosition}% position to insert new element
% insert #1 into the next position of \newRandomList unless the position
% index \randomListPosition is equal to \newRandomListElementPosition in
% which case the \newRandomListElement is added first
\newcommand\randomlyInsertElement[1]{%
  \stepcounter{randomListPosition}%
  \ifnum\value{randomListPosition}=\value{newRandomListElementPosition}%
    \listxadd\newRandomList{\newRandomListElement}%
  \fi%
  \listxadd\newRandomList{#1}%
}
% \randomlyInsertInList{list name}{new list length}{new element}
\newcommand\randomlyInsertInList[3]{%
  \pgfmathparse{random(1,#2)}%
  \setcounter{newRandomListElementPosition}{\pgfmathresult}%
  \ifnum\value{newRandomListElementPosition}=#2\relax%
    \listcsxadd{#1}{#3}%
  \else%
    \def\newRandomList{}% start with an empty list
    \def\newRandomListElement{#3}% and the element that we need to add
    \setcounter{randomListPosition}{0}% starting from position 0
    \xdef\currentList{\csuse{#1}}
    \forlistloop\randomlyInsertElement\currentList%
    \csxdef{#1}{\newRandomList}%
  \fi%
}
% define some pgfkeys to allow key-value arguments
\pgfkeys{/randomList/.is family, /randomList,
  environment/.code = {\global\letcs\beginRandomListEnvironment{#1}
                       \global\letcs\endRandomListEnvironment{end#1}
                      },
  enumerate/.style = {environment=enumerate},
  itemize/.style = {environment=itemize},
  description/.style = {environment=description},
  seed/.code = {\pgfmathsetseed{#1}}
}
\pgfkeys{/randomList, enumerate}% enumerate is the default

% finally, the code to construct the randomly permuted list
\makeatletter
\newcounter{randomListCounter}% for constructing \randomListItem@<k>'s

% \useRandomItem{k} prints item number k
\newcommand\useRandomItem[1]{\csname randomListItem@#1\endcsname}

% \setRandomItem{k} saves item number k for future use
% and builds a random permutation at the same time
\def\setRandomItem#1\par{\stepcounter{randomListCounter}%
       \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname randomListItem@\therandomListCounter\endcsname{\noexpand\item#1}%
       \randomlyInsertInList{randomlyOrderedList}{\therandomListCounter}{\therandomListCounter}%
}%
\let\realitem=\item
\makeatother
\newenvironment{randomList}[1][]{% optional argument -> pgfkeys
  \pgfkeys{/randomList, #1}% process optional arguments
  \setcounter{randomListLength}{0}% initialise length of random list
  \def\randomlyOrderedList{}% initialise the random list of items
  % Nthing is printed in the main environment. Instead, \item is
  % used to slurp the "contents" of the item into randomListItem@<counter>
  \let\item\setRandomItem%      
}
{% now construct the list environment by looping over the randomly ordered list
  \let\item\realitem
  \setcounter{randomListCounter}{0}
  \beginRandomListEnvironment\relax
    \forlistloop\useRandomItem\randomlyOrderedList
  \endRandomListEnvironment
}
% test compatibility with enumitem
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Testlist}{enumerate}{1} %
\setlist[Testlist]{label*=\alph*)}
\setlist{nosep}\parindent=0pt% for more compact output




%----------- PARA CRIAR PÁGINA EM BRANCO, CASO NÚMERO DE PÁGINAS SEJA ÍMPAR --------------------
\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
%----------- DESCOMENTAR "\afterpage{\blankpage}" AO FINAL DO DOCUMENTO ------------------------




%-----------     RELACIONADO AO CABEÇALHO E RODAPÉ     -----------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\titlee}{\textbf{Exam 1 - Physics}}
\newcommand{\data}{\today}
\newcommand{\valor}{12,0}
%\newcommand{\class}{\phantom{CTAII-2V}} % Não adicionar nome da turma
\newcommand{\class}{CTAII-2V}            % Adicionar nome da turma




\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt} % linha no footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.2pt}% linha no header 

\rhead{\ttfamily \titlee{}}
\lfoot{\ttfamily Prof. Lucas }
\rfoot{\ttfamily \data{}}

\pagestyle{fancy} 

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \lhead{%
    \def\scale{0.6}%
    \def\roundc{\scale*0.1cm}% rc = 10% de sc
    \raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\scale]
      \definecolor{tempcolor}{RGB}{200,25,30}
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (2cm,0cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-0.5cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (2cm,-0.6cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.1cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (2cm,-0.6cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-1.1cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (1.7cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (0.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (1.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.8cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (1.7cm,-1.8cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-2.3cm);
      \node[scale=\scale,fill=white] at (5.92,-0.85) {\resizebox{6.7cm}{0.5cm}{\sffamily \textbf{PHANTOM}}};
      \node[scale=\scale,fill=white] at (4.52,-1.55) {\resizebox{5cm}{0.5cm}{\sffamily {School}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
  }
  \chead{\raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\rule[-2.5\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}}
  \rhead{\raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
    \tikz \node at (0,0) {\titlee{}};\\ 
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=6.5cm,
    minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label
    distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Name}:}] {\ttfamily \myname};} 
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Sign.}:}] {\phantom{\ttfamily 15,0}};}    
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Class}:}] {\ttfamily \class};}   
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Marks}:}] {\ttfamily 15,0};} 
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Nota}:}] {\phantom{\ttfamily 15,0}};}
    \end{tabular}}
  }
  \lfoot{\ttfamily Prof. Lucas}
  \rfoot{\ttfamily \today}
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \thispagestyle{firststyle}
  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445369/121799
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{students.csv}
name 
{Cosmic Cuttlefish}
{Bionic Beaver}
{Xenial Xerus}
{Trusty Tahr}
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%----------- PARA ADICIONAR CÍRCULO NEGRO À NUMERAÇÃO -------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*\circleded[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
    \node[
      shape=circle,
      fill,
      inner sep=1.5pt,
      text=white,
      minimum size=1.5em
    ] (char) {#1};
}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{students.csv}\loadedtable
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownum}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\foreach \X in {0,...,\rownum}
{\ReadOutElement{\loadedtable}{\X}{name}{\tmpname}
\xdef\myname{\tmpname}
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\vspace*{2\baselineskip}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{21.5em}
\begin{center}
\vspace{2mm}
{\sffamily\small \bf INSTRUCTIONS}
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
{\footnotesize
   \item SIGN YOUR NAME ON THIS SHEET.
   \item BE SURE EACH MARK IS DARK AND COMPLETELY FILLS THE INTEENDED SPACE.
   \item USE ONLY A PENCIL WITH SOFT, BLACK LEAD (Nº 2 OR HB) TO COMPLETE THE ANSWER SHEET.
   \item COMPLETELY ERASE ANY ERRORS OT STRAY MARKS.\\
}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}

%%%%%%%%%%% PARA O CARTÃO-RESPOSTA %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{20em}
\begin{center}
\item 
{\sffamily\small
\textbf{ANSWER SHEET}\vspace{6pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\sffamily}] % sans serif font (like Arial)
  \foreach \col in {0,1} { %total number of columns of answers -1
   \begin{scope}[xshift=\col*3.2 cm]
    \foreach \line in {1,2,...,4} { %%% ESPECIFICAR AQUI O NÚMERO DE LINHAS
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-.6*\line cm]
        \pgfmathparse{int(Mod(\line,2))?"gray!30":"white"} % alternating row colours
        \edef\filler{\pgfmathresult}

                \draw [fill=\filler] (-.22,-.35) rectangle(2.8cm,.7em);
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro\q{(4*\col)+\line}  %%% O FATOR MULTIPLICATIVO DE \col DEVE SER O NÚMERO DE LINHAS
           \node at (0,-.05) {\textbf{\q}}; %print line number

          \footnotesize \foreach \count/\desc in {1/A, 2/B, 3/C, 4/D, 5/E} { % \desc = value in circle
                %\node at ({\count * 0.5}, 0.4) {\desc};
                %\node (rect) at (0,0){};

                \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.6pt] at ({\count * 0.5},-.05) {\desc}; %print letter in circle
            }
        \end{scope}
    } %end of foreach set of lines
    \end{scope} %each column region
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{enumerate}
%%%%%%% PARA ADICIONAR CÍRCULO NEGRO À NUMERAÇÃO %%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\bfseries\circleded{\theenumi}} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



 \item {\framebox{\scriptsize \sf 1,5}} When a certain force is applied to an object with a mass of 2 kg, its acceleration is 10.0 m/s$^2$. When the same force is applied to a different object, its acceleration is 4.0 m/s$^2$. The mass of second object is
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{randomList}[environment=Testlist]
\item 10.0 kg

\item 8.0 kg

\item 5.0 kg

\item 2.5 kg

\item 1.25 kg

  \end{randomList}


\vspace{1cm} 


 \item {\framebox{\scriptsize \sf 1,5}} If a firefly collides with the windshield of a fast-moving bus, which statement is correct?
  \begin{randomList}[environment=Testlist]
   \item The firefly experiences an impact force with a larger magnitude

   \item The bus experiences an impact force with a larger magnitude

   \item The firefly and bus experience forces with same direction

   \item The firefly and bus experience forces with same magnitude

   \item None of the above

  \end{randomList}


\vspace{1cm} 


\item  {\framebox{\scriptsize \sf 1,5}} The tension in a string from which a 4.0-kg object is suspended in an elevator is equal to 44 N. What is the acceleration of the elevator?
\vspace{2mm} 
  \begin{randomList}[environment=Testlist]
   \item 11 m/s$^2$ upward

   \item 1.2 m/s$^2$ upward

   \item 1.2 m/s$^2$ downward

   \item 10 m/s$^2$ upward

   \item 2.4 m/s$^2$ downward

  \end{randomList} 


\vspace{1cm} 


\item  {\framebox{\scriptsize \sf 1,5}} What is the smallest value of the force F such that the 2.0-kg block will not slide down the wall? The coefficient of static friction between the block and the wall is 0.2.
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{randomList}[environment=Testlist]
   \item 98 N

   \item 20 N

   \item 10 N

   \item 4 N

   \item 2 N

\end{randomList}  


\vspace{1cm} 


\item {\framebox{\scriptsize \sf 1,5}} In a game of shuffleboard (played on a horizontal surface), a puck is given an initial speed of 6.0 m/s. It slides a distance of 9.0 m before coming to rest. What is the coefficient of kinetic friction between the puck and the surface?
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{randomList}[environment=Testlist]
   \item 0.20

   \item 0.18

   \item 0.15

   \item 0.13

   \item 0.27

\end{randomList}   


\vspace{1cm}  


\item {\framebox{\scriptsize \sf 1,5}} A 3.0-kg block slides on a frictionless 20º inclined plane. A force of 16 N acting parallel to the incline and up the incline is applied to the block. What is the acceleration of the block?
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{randomList}[environment=Testlist]
\item  2.0 m/s$^2$ down the incline

\item  5.3 m/s$^2$ up the incline

\item  2.0 m/s$^2$ up the incline

\item  3.9 m/s$^2$ down the incline

\item  3.9 m/s$^2$ up the incline

\end{randomList}     


\vspace{1cm}  


\item {\framebox{\scriptsize \sf 1,5}} An airplane flies in a horizontal circle of radius 500 m at a speed of 150 m/s. If the plane were to fly in the same 1000 m circle at a speed of 300 m/s, by what factor would its centripetal acceleration change?
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{randomList}[environment=Testlist]
\item  0.25

\item  0.50

\item  1.00

\item  2.00

\item  4.00

\end{randomList}  


\vspace{1cm}  


\item {\framebox{\scriptsize \sf 1,5}} A 5-kg ball hangs at one end of a string that is attached to a support on a railroad boxcar. When the boxcar accelerates to the right, the rope makes an angle of 30º with the vertical. The acceleration of gravity is 9.8 m/s$^2$ and air resistance is negligible. Find the acceleration of the boxcar.
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{randomList}[environment=Testlist]
\item  56.6 m/s$^2$

\item  49.0 m/s$^2$

\item  17.0 m/s$^2$

\item  9.8 m/s$^2$

\item  5.7 m/s$^2$

\end{randomList}    



\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols} % fim ambiente 2 ou + cols.
%\afterpage{\blankpage}
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I've done something similar using the `textmerg` package.

Comment: @JPi , could you be more specific in your answer?