# Using a data file as input in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, tikz-datavisualization

I have a sorted data in a file (named data.dat). These data should be plotted vertically. I prepared a code in latex using tikz that works. The problem is each data is typed one by one in the main body of the code and I need a way in which I call the data file and each data is substituted one by one. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[border= 5 pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{times,comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\point}[1]{
\draw [<->,purple] ( 0 , #1 ) node[yshift=0,left,font=\tiny]{  #1 }  -- ( 1 , #1 ) node[yshift=0,right,font=\tiny]{  #1 } ; }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\point{0}    
\point{1}
\point{2}
\point{2.5}    
\point{3.4}
\point{4}
\point{5.8}
\point{6.9}
\point{7.5}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The data file can be download from [here.](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=25916905667656235470)

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by Henri Menke, you could use pgfplots to plot the data. Assuming you want to use Ti*k*Z and your command `\point` instead, you could use `pgfplotstable` to load and loop over the data. (You won't need `\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}` ... `\end{filecontents*}` because you already have `data.dat`, this is just to make it more convenient for others to get the file on their system.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
0
1
2
2.5
3.4
4
5.8
6.9
7.5
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445369/121799
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}
\newcommand{\point}[1]{
\draw [<->,purple] ( 0 , #1 ) node[yshift=0,left,font=\tiny]{  #1 }  -- ( 1 , #1 ) node[yshift=0,right,font=\tiny]{  #1 } ; }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{data.dat}\datatable
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownum}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\foreach \X in {0,...,\rownum}
{\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\X}{[index]0}{\tmpx}
\point{\tmpx}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although in this case you can use pgfplots lo load the external data (+1) and in other type of macros probably you can also  use the `datatool` package, in case you know R and `knitr`,  here are another approach to access individual values as argument of a macro: load the external data as an R data frame object, said with name "data",  and then access concrete values of this vector as  `\Sexpr{data[3,1]}` (print the third value of first column).

To load the external CSV file as a data.frame, you can use the `read.csv()` R function but for the example I created the data frame from the scratch:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{times,comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\point}[1]{
\draw [<->,purple] ( 0 , #1 ) node[yshift=0,left,
font=\tiny]{  #1 }  -- ( 1 , #1 ) node[yshift=0,right,font=\tiny]{  #1 } ; }
\begin{document}
<<mydata,echo=F>>=
# data <- read.csv("data.dat", sep=",", header=F) # to load external data
data <- data.frame(x=c(0,1,2,2.5,3.4,4,5.8,6.9,7.5)) # internal data
@
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\point{\Sexpr{data[1,1]}}    
\point{\Sexpr{data[2,1]}}    
\point{\Sexpr{data[3,1]}}    
\point{\Sexpr{data[4,1]}}    
\point{\Sexpr{data[5,1]}}    
\point{\Sexpr{data[6,1]}}    
\point{\Sexpr{data[7,1]}}    
\point{\Sexpr{data[8,1]}}    
\point{\Sexpr{data[9,1]}}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(The result is identical to the image of marmot, no need to add it twice).