# Drawing two curves from a csv file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, csv

Hello fellows and folks!

I am working with python and I need to draw the following picture in latex by using the values from the variables. They are a ton, so it is not like the usual stuff where I plot 10 (x,y) points. How can I use those file and get the same plot as in the picture

It looks something like this:

[image]

Users' csv file structure:

```
user_index  user_counts
0   20
0.000165562913907   20
0.000331125827815   20
0.000496688741722   20
0.000662251655629   20
0.000827814569536   20
0.000993377483444   20
0.001158940397351   20
0.001324503311258   20
0.001490066225166   20
0.001655629139073   20
0.00182119205298    20
0.247682119205298   44
0.247847682119205   44
0.248013245033113   44
0.24817880794702    44
0.248344370860927   44
0.248509933774834   44
0.248675496688742   44
0.248841059602649   44
0.249006622516556   44
0.249172185430464   44
0.249337748344371   44
0.249503311258278   44
0.249668874172185   44
0.249834437086093   44
0.25    44
0.250165562913907   44
0.250331125827815   44
0.250496688741722   44
0.250662251655629   44
0.250827814569536   44
0.250993377483444   44
0.251158940397351   44
0.251324503311258   44
0.251490066225166   44
0.251655629139073   44
0.25182119205298    44
0.251986754966887   45
0.252152317880795   45
0.252317880794702   45
0.252483443708609   45
0.252649006622517   45
0.252814569536424   45
0.252980132450331   45
0.253145695364238   45
0.253311258278146   45
0.253476821192053   45
0.25364238410596    45
0.253807947019868   45
0.253973509933775   45
0.254139072847682   45
0.254304635761589   45
0.254470198675497   45
0.254635761589404   45
0.254801324503311   45
0.254966887417219   45
0.255132450331126   45
0.255298013245033   45
0.25546357615894    45
0.255629139072848   45
0.255794701986755   45
0.255960264900662   45
0.25612582781457    45
0.256291390728477   45
0.256456953642384   45
0.256622516556291   45
0.256788079470199   45
0.256953642384106   45
0.257119205298013   45
0.25728476821192    45
0.257450331125828   45
0.257615894039735   45
0.257781456953642   45
0.25794701986755    45
0.258112582781457   45
0.258278145695364   45
0.258443708609271   45
0.258609271523179   46
0.258774834437086   46
0.258940397350993   46
0.259105960264901   46
0.259271523178808   46
0.259437086092715   46
0.259602649006622   46
0.25976821192053    46
0.259933774834437   46
0.260099337748344   46
0.260264900662252   46
0.260430463576159   46
0.260596026490066   46
0.260761589403974   46
0.260927152317881   46
0.261092715231788   46
0.261258278145695   46
0.261423841059603   46
0.26158940397351    46
0.261754966887417   46
0.261920529801325   46
0.262086092715232   46
0.262251655629139   46
0.262417218543046   46
0.262582781456954   46
0.262748344370861   46
0.262913907284768   46
0.263079470198675   46
0.263245033112583   46
0.26341059602649    46
0.263576158940397   46
0.263741721854305   46
0.263907284768212   46
0.264072847682119   46
0.264238410596026   46
0.264403973509934   46
0.264569536423841   46
0.264735099337748   46
0.264900662251656   46
0.265066225165563   46
0.26523178807947    46
0.265397350993377   46
0.265562913907285   46
0.265728476821192   46
0.265894039735099   46
0.266059602649007   46
0.266225165562914   47
0.266390728476821   47
0.266556291390728   47
0.266721854304636   47
0.266887417218543   47
0.26705298013245    47
0.267218543046358   47
0.267384105960265   47
0.267549668874172   47
0.267715231788079   47
0.267880794701987   47
0.268046357615894   47
0.268211920529801   47
0.268377483443709   47
0.268543046357616   47
0.268708609271523   47
0.26887417218543    47
0.269039735099338   47
0.269205298013245   47
0.269370860927152   47
0.26953642384106    47
0.269701986754967   47
0.269867549668874   47
0.270033112582781   47
0.270198675496689   47
0.270364238410596   47
0.270529801324503   47
0.270695364238411   47
0.270860927152318   47
0.271026490066225   47
0.271192052980132   47
0.27135761589404    47
0.271523178807947   47
0.271688741721854   47
0.271854304635762   47
0.272019867549669   47
0.272185430463576   47
0.272350993377483   47
0.272516556291391   47
0.272682119205298   47
0.272847682119205   47
0.273013245033113   47
0.27317880794702    47
0.273344370860927   47
0.273509933774834   47
0.273675496688742   47
0.273841059602649   47
0.274006622516556   47
0.274172185430464   47
0.274337748344371   47
0.274503311258278   47
0.274668874172185   47
0.274834437086093   47
0.275   47
0.275165562913907   47
0.275331125827815   48
0.275496688741722   48
0.275662251655629   48
0.275827814569536   48
0.275993377483444   48
0.276158940397351   48
0.276324503311258   48
0.276490066225166   48
0.276655629139073   48
0.27682119205298    48
0.276986754966887   48
0.277152317880795   48
0.277317880794702   48
0.277483443708609   48
0.277649006622517   48
0.277814569536424   48
0.277980132450331   48
0.278145695364238   48
0.278311258278146   48
0.278476821192053   48
0.27864238410596    48
0.278807947019868   48
0.278973509933775   48
0.279139072847682   48
0.279304635761589   48
0.279470198675497   48
0.279635761589404   48
0.279801324503311   48
0.279966887417219   48
0.280132450331126   48
0.280298013245033   48
0.28046357615894    48
0.280629139072848   48
0.280794701986755   48
0.280960264900662   48
0.281125827814569   48
0.281291390728477   48
0.281456953642384   48
0.281622516556291   48
0.281788079470199   48
0.281953642384106   48
0.282119205298013   48
0.282284768211921   48
0.282450331125828   48
0.282615894039735   48
0.282781456953642   48
0.28294701986755    48
0.283112582781457   48
0.283278145695364   48
0.283443708609272   48
0.283609271523179   48
0.283774834437086   49
0.283940397350993   49
0.284105960264901   49
0.284271523178808   49
0.284437086092715   49
0.284602649006622   49
0.28476821192053    49
0.284933774834437   49
0.285099337748344   49
0.285264900662252   49
0.285430463576159   49
0.285596026490066   49
0.285761589403973   49
0.285927152317881   49
0.286092715231788   49
0.286258278145695   49
0.286423841059603   49
0.28658940397351    49
0.286754966887417   49
0.286920529801324   49
0.287086092715232   49
0.287251655629139   49
0.287417218543046   49
0.287582781456954   49
0.287748344370861   49
0.287913907284768   49
0.288079470198676   49
0.288245033112583   49
0.28841059602649    49
0.288576158940397   50
0.288741721854305   50
0.288907284768212   50
0.289072847682119   50
0.289238410596026   50
0.289403973509934   50
0.289569536423841   50
0.289735099337748   50
0.289900662251656   50
0.290066225165563   50
0.29023178807947    50
0.290397350993377   50
0.290562913907285   50
0.290728476821192   50
0.290894039735099   50
0.291059602649007   50
0.291225165562914   50
0.291390728476821   50
0.291556291390728   50
0.291721854304636   50
0.291887417218543   50
0.29205298013245    50
0.292218543046358   50
0.292384105960265   50
0.292549668874172   50
0.292715231788079   50
0.292880794701987   50
0.293046357615894   50
0.293211920529801   50
0.293377483443709   50
0.293543046357616   50
0.293708609271523   50
0.29387417218543    50
0.294039735099338   50
0.294205298013245   50
0.294370860927152   50
0.29453642384106    50
0.294701986754967   50
0.294867549668874   50
0.295033112582781   50
0.295198675496689   50
0.295364238410596   50
0.295529801324503   50
0.295695364238411   50
0.295860927152318   50
0.296026490066225   50
0.296192052980133   50
0.29635761589404    50
0.296523178807947   50
0.296688741721854   50
0.296854304635762   51
0.297019867549669   51
0.297185430463576   51
0.297350993377483   51
0.297516556291391   51
0.297682119205298   51
0.297847682119205   51
0.298013245033113   51
0.29817880794702    51
0.298344370860927   51
0.298509933774834   51
0.298675496688742   51
0.298841059602649   51
0.299006622516556   51
0.299172185430464   51
0.299337748344371   51
0.299503311258278   51
0.299668874172185   51
0.299834437086093   51
0.3 51
0.300165562913907   51
0.300331125827815   51
0.300496688741722   51
0.300662251655629   51
0.300827814569536   51
0.300993377483444   51
0.301158940397351   51
0.301324503311258   51
0.301490066225166   51
0.301655629139073   51
0.30182119205298    51
0.301986754966887   51
0.302152317880795   51
0.302317880794702   51
0.302483443708609   51
0.302649006622517   51
0.302814569536424   51
0.302980132450331   51
0.303145695364238   51
0.303311258278146   51
0.303476821192053   51
0.30364238410596    51
0.303807947019868   52
0.303973509933775   52
0.304139072847682   52
0.304304635761589   52
0.304470198675497   52
0.304635761589404   52
0.304801324503311   52
0.304966887417219   52
0.305132450331126   52
0.305298013245033   52
0.30546357615894    52
0.305629139072848   52
0.305794701986755   52
0.305960264900662   52
0.30612582781457    52
0.306291390728477   52
0.306456953642384   52
0.306622516556291   52
0.306788079470199   52
0.306953642384106   52
0.307119205298013   52
0.30728476821192    52
0.307450331125828   52
0.307615894039735   52
0.307781456953642   52
0.30794701986755    52
0.308112582781457   52
0.308278145695364   52
0.308443708609271   52
0.308609271523179   52
0.308774834437086   52
0.308940397350993   52
0.309105960264901   52
0.309271523178808   52
0.309437086092715   52
0.309602649006622   52
0.30976821192053    52
0.309933774834437   52
0.310099337748344   52
0.310264900662252   53
0.310430463576159   53
0.310596026490066   53
0.310761589403973   53
0.310927152317881   53
0.311092715231788   53
0.311258278145695   53
0.311423841059603   53
0.31158940397351    53
0.311754966887417   53
0.311920529801324   53
0.312086092715232   53
0.312251655629139   53
0.312417218543046   53
0.312582781456954   53
0.312748344370861   53
0.312913907284768   53
0.313079470198675   53
0.313245033112583   53
0.31341059602649    53
0.313576158940397   53
0.313741721854305   53
0.313907284768212   53
0.314072847682119   53
0.314238410596026   53
0.314403973509934   53
0.314569536423841   53
0.314735099337748   53
0.314900662251656   53
0.315066225165563   53
0.31523178807947    53
0.315397350993377   53
0.315562913907285   53
0.315728476821192   53
0.315894039735099   53
0.316059602649007   54
0.316225165562914   54
0.316390728476821   54
0.316556291390728   54
0.316721854304636   54
0.316887417218543   54
0.31705298013245    54
0.317218543046358   54
0.317384105960265   54
0.317549668874172   54
0.317715231788079   54
0.317880794701987   54
0.318046357615894   54
0.318211920529801   54
0.318377483443709   54
0.318543046357616   54
0.318708609271523   54
0.31887417218543    54
0.319039735099338   54
0.319205298013245   54
0.319370860927152   54
0.31953642384106    54
0.319701986754967   54
0.319867549668874   54
0.320033112582781   54
0.320198675496689   54
0.320364238410596   54
0.320529801324503   54
0.320695364238411   54
0.320860927152318   54
0.321026490066225   55
0.321192052980132   55
0.32135761589404    55
0.321523178807947   55
0.321688741721854   55
0.321854304635762   55
0.322019867549669   55
0.322185430463576   55
0.322350993377483   55
0.322516556291391   55
0.322682119205298   55
0.322847682119205   55
0.323013245033113   55
0.32317880794702    55
0.323344370860927   55
0.323509933774834   55
0.323675496688742   55
0.323841059602649   55
0.324006622516556   55
0.324172185430464   55
0.324337748344371   55
0.324503311258278   55
0.324668874172185   55
0.324834437086093   55
0.325   55
0.325165562913907   55
0.325331125827815   55
0.325496688741722   55
0.325662251655629   55
0.325827814569536   55
0.325993377483444   55
0.326158940397351   55
0.326324503311258   55
0.326490066225166   55
0.326655629139073   55
0.32682119205298    55
0.326986754966887   55
```

Movies' csv file structure:

```
user_index  user_counts
0   20
0.000165562913907   20
0.000331125827815   20
0.000496688741722   20
0.000662251655629   20
0.000827814569536   20
0.000993377483444   20
0.001158940397351   20
0.001324503311258   20
0.001490066225166   20
0.001655629139073   20
0.00182119205298    20
0.001986754966887   20
0.002152317880795   20
0.002317880794702   20
0.002483443708609   20
0.002649006622517   20
0.002814569536424   20
0.002980132450331   20
0.003145695364238   20
0.003311258278146   20
0.003476821192053   20
0.00364238410596    20
0.003807947019868   20
0.003973509933775   20
0.004139072847682   20
0.004304635761589   20
0.004470198675497   20
0.004635761589404   20
0.004801324503311   20
0.004966887417219   20
0.005132450331126   20
0.005298013245033   20
0.00546357615894    20
0.005629139072848   20
0.005794701986755   20
0.005960264900662   20
0.00612582781457    20
0.006291390728477   20
0.006456953642384   20
0.006622516556291   20
0.006788079470199   20
0.006953642384106   20
0.007119205298013   20
0.007284768211921   20
0.007450331125828   20
0.007615894039735   20
0.007781456953642   20
0.00794701986755    20
0.008112582781457   20
0.008278145695364   20
0.008443708609272   20
0.008609271523179   20
0.008774834437086   20
0.008940397350993   20
0.009105960264901   20
0.009271523178808   20
0.009437086092715   20
0.009602649006623   20
0.00976821192053    20
0.009933774834437   20
0.010099337748344   20
0.010264900662252   20
0.010430463576159   20
0.010596026490066   20
0.010761589403974   20
0.010927152317881   20
0.011092715231788   20
0.011258278145695   20
0.011423841059603   20
0.01158940397351    20
0.011754966887417   20
0.011920529801325   20
0.012086092715232   20
0.012251655629139   20
0.012417218543046   20
0.012582781456954   20
0.012748344370861   20
0.012913907284768   20
0.013079470198676   20
0.013245033112583   20
0.01341059602649    20
0.013576158940397   20
0.013741721854305   20
0.013907284768212   20
0.014072847682119   20
0.014238410596027   21
0.014403973509934   21
0.014569536423841   21
0.014735099337748   21
0.014900662251656   21
0.015066225165563   21
0.01523178807947    21
0.015397350993378   21
0.015562913907285   21
0.015728476821192   21
0.015894039735099   21
0.016059602649007   21
0.016225165562914   21
0.016390728476821   21
0.016556291390729   21
0.016721854304636   21
0.016887417218543   21
0.01705298013245    21
0.017218543046358   21
0.017384105960265   21
0.017549668874172   21
0.01771523178808    21
0.017880794701987   21
0.018046357615894   21
0.018211920529801   21
0.018377483443709   21
0.018543046357616   21
0.018708609271523   21
0.018874172185431   21
0.019039735099338   21
0.019205298013245   21
0.019370860927152   21
0.01953642384106    21
0.019701986754967   21
0.019867549668874   21
0.020033112582782   21
0.020198675496689   21
0.020364238410596   21
0.020529801324503   21
0.020695364238411   21
0.020860927152318   21
0.021026490066225   21
0.021192052980133   21
0.02135761589404    21
0.021523178807947   21
0.021688741721854   21
0.021854304635762   21
0.022019867549669   21
0.022185430463576   21
0.022350993377484   21
0.022516556291391   21
0.022682119205298   21
0.022847682119205   21
0.023013245033113   21
0.02317880794702    21
0.023344370860927   21
0.023509933774835   21
0.023675496688742   21
0.023841059602649   21
0.024006622516556   21
0.024172185430464   21
0.024337748344371   21
0.024503311258278   21
0.024668874172186   21
0.024834437086093   21
0.025   21
0.025165562913907   21
0.025331125827815   21
0.025496688741722   21
0.025662251655629   21
0.025827814569537   21
0.025993377483444   21
0.026158940397351   21
0.026324503311258   21
0.026490066225166   21
0.026655629139073   21
0.02682119205298    21
0.026986754966888   21
0.027152317880795   21
0.027317880794702   21
0.027483443708609   21
0.027649006622517   21
0.027814569536424   21
0.027980132450331   21
0.028145695364239   21
0.028311258278146   21
0.028476821192053   21
0.02864238410596    21
```

This MWE seems to be working but it prints a histogram instead lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    x_values    y_frequency
    0.000165562913907   20
    0.000331125827815   20
    0.000496688741722   20
    0.000662251655629   20
    0.000827814569536   20  
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445369/121799
\newcommand*{\ReadOutElement}[4]{%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{#2}{#3}\of{#1}%
    \let#4\pgfplotsretval
}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[header=true]{data.csv}\datatable
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rownum}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\rownum}
    {\ReadOutElement{\datatable}{\X}{x_values}{\tmpx}
        \ifnum\X=0
        \xdef\lstSymbCoords{{\tmpx}}
        \else
        \xdef\lstSymbCoords{\lstSymbCoords,{\tmpx}}
        \fi}
    %\typeout{\lstSymbCoords}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        ymin=0,
        symbolic x coords={\lstSymbCoords},
        xticklabel style={
            rotate=90,
            anchor=east}
        ]}
    \temp
    \addplot[
    % hist={
    %     bins=7,
    %     data min=0.5,
    %     %data max=4
    % }   
    ] table [x=x_values,y=y_frequency] {\datatable};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `ybar` makes a bar chart. I think your code is a lot more complicated than it needs be though, try removing all the `\ReadOutElement` and `\lstSymbCoords` stuff, and start with just `\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}   \addplot table {data1.csv}; \addplot table {data2.csv}; \end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}`. Do you want to change the background colour as well?

Comment: I would love to change the background color as well!!! Also, I put csv, but it is a tab separated file

Comment: I may have misunderstood. Do want to plot the values in the files directly, or is there some calculation involved? (You weren't very specific.) I also just remembered that if you have done this with `matplotlib` already, you could try using `matplotlib2tikz` to generate a file with `pgfplots` code.

Comment: I wanted to plot the values from the files directly! I will try matplotlib2tikz, I didn’t know about it

Comment: what is the main goal?  are you using LaTeX to do the plotting so you have all the fonts embedded?

Comment: @jeschwar Yes, exactly! So, I have all the *PLOTS* embedded

Comment: IIUC then you should be able to do this all in matplotlib by updating `rcParams` with `rc('pdf', fonttype=42)` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054884/how-to-embed-fonts-in-pdfs-produced-by-matplotlib)

Comment: Thank you but it is not the same. Once you have the tikz picture's code, you can play with it and change it to your own taste. That's what I did. On the contrary, if you use the matplotlib library, you get one plot only and that's it. No coordinates etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used a lot of code that you don't actually need I think, and the reason you get a histogram is `ybar`, which makes the plot a bar chart. As I mention in a comment, the basic setup you need is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot table {movies.csv};
    \addplot table {users.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This works when you have just two columns in the files, and the columns are separated by white space. If not told otherwise, `pgfplots` will use the first column of a file for the x-values, and the second for the y-values.

To do the styling you need a bit more code. In the example below I wrapped most of the stuff in a style, which makes it easier to reuse it, should you need more diagrams with the same basic look.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{movies.csv}
    x_values    y_frequency
    0.000165562913907   20
    0.000331125827815   20
    0.000496688741722   20
    0.000662251655629   20
    0.000827814569536   20  
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{users.csv}
user_index  user_counts
0   20
0.000165562913907   20
0.000331125827815   20
0.000496688741722   20
0.000662251655629   20
0.000827814569536   20
0.000993377483444   20
0.001158940397351   20
0.001324503311258   20
0.001490066225166   20
0.001655629139073   20
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{
   compat=1.16,
   MyAxisStyle/.style={ % define a new style for the axis, makes reuse easier
     grid=major, % activate grid lines
     grid style={white}, % and make them white
     axis background/.style={fill=black!20}, % fill background
     axis line style={draw=none}, % don't draw axis box
     tickwidth=0pt,% don't draw ticks
     scaled x ticks=false, % don't scale ticklabels by some factor of ten
     xticklabel style={
       /pgf/number format/fixed, % don't use scientific notation for ticklabels
       /pgf/number format/precision=3 % set number of decimals
    }
  },
}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  MyAxisStyle, % use the style defined earlier
  only marks
  ]
    \addplot [mark=*, orange] table {movies.csv};
    \addplot [mark=*, blue] table {users.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

INCREDIBLE! THANK YOU Torbjorn!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

    % This file was created by matplotlib2tikz v0.7.4.
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.917647058823529,0.917647058823529,0.949019607843137}
    \definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
    \definecolor{color2}{rgb}{1,0.498039215686275,0.0549019607843137}

    \begin{axis}[
    axis background/.style={fill=color0},
    axis line style={white},
    legend cell align={left},
    legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)}, anchor=south east, draw=none, fill=color0},
    tick align=outside,
    tick pos=left,
    x grid style={white},
    xlabel={Number of Ratings},
    xmajorgrids,
    xmin=-35.8, xmax=773.8,
    xtick style={color=white!15.0!black},
    y grid style={white},
    ylabel={ECDF},
    ymajorgrids,
    ymin=-0.0499702734839477, ymax=1.0493757431629,
    ytick style={color=white!15.0!black}
    ]
    \addplot [thick, color1, mark=*, mark size=3, mark options={solid}, only marks]
    table {%
        20 0
        20 0.00106044538706257
        20 0.00212089077412513
        20 0.0031813361611877
        20 0.00424178154825027
        20 0.00530222693531283
        20 0.0063626723223754
        20 0.00742311770943796
        20 0.00848356309650053
        20 0.0095440084835631
        20 0.0106044538706257
        20 0.0116648992576882
        20 0.0127253446447508
        20 0.0137857900318134
        20 0.0148462354188759
        20 0.0159066808059385
        20 0.0169671261930011
        20 0.0180275715800636
        20 0.0190880169671262
        20 0.0201484623541888
        20 0.0212089077412513
        20 0.0222693531283139
        20 0.0233297985153765
        20 0.024390243902439
        20 0.0254506892895016
        20 0.0265111346765642
        20 0.0275715800636267
        20 0.0286320254506893
        20 0.0296924708377519
        20 0.0307529162248144
        20 0.031813361611877
        20 0.0328738069989396
        21 0.0339342523860021
        21 0.0349946977730647
        21 0.0360551431601273
        21 0.0371155885471898
        21 0.0381760339342524
        21 0.039236479321315
        21 0.0402969247083775
        21 0.0413573700954401
        21 0.0424178154825027
        21 0.0434782608695652
        21 0.0445387062566278
        21 0.0455991516436903
        21 0.0466595970307529
        21 0.0477200424178155
        21 0.0487804878048781
        21 0.0498409331919406
        21 0.0509013785790032
        21 0.0519618239660657
        21 0.0530222693531283
        21 0.0540827147401909
        21 0.0551431601272534
        21 0.056203605514316
        21 0.0572640509013786
        21 0.0583244962884411
        22 0.0593849416755037
        22 0.0604453870625663
        22 0.0615058324496288
        22 0.0625662778366914
        22 0.063626723223754
        22 0.0646871686108165
        22 0.0657476139978791
        22 0.0668080593849417
        22 0.0678685047720042
        22 0.0689289501590668
        22 0.0699893955461294
        22 0.0710498409331919
        22 0.0721102863202545
        22 0.0731707317073171
        22 0.0742311770943796
        22 0.0752916224814422
        22 0.0763520678685048
        22 0.0774125132555673
        22 0.0784729586426299
        22 0.0795334040296925
        22 0.080593849416755
        22 0.0816542948038176
        22 0.0827147401908802
        23 0.0837751855779427
        23 0.0848356309650053
        23 0.0858960763520679
        23 0.0869565217391304
        23 0.088016967126193
        23 0.0890774125132556
        23 0.0901378579003181
        23 0.0911983032873807
        23 0.0922587486744433
        23 0.0933191940615058
        23 0.0943796394485684
        23 0.095440084835631
        23 0.0965005302226935
        23 0.0975609756097561
        23 0.0986214209968187
        23 0.0996818663838812
        23 0.100742311770944
        23 0.101802757158006
        23 0.102863202545069
        23 0.103923647932131
        23 0.104984093319194
        24 0.106044538706257
        24 0.107104984093319
        24 0.108165429480382
        24 0.109225874867444
        24 0.110286320254507
        24 0.111346765641569
        24 0.112407211028632
        24 0.113467656415695
        24 0.114528101802757
        24 0.11558854718982
        24 0.116648992576882
        24 0.117709437963945
        24 0.118769883351007
        24 0.11983032873807
        24 0.120890774125133
        24 0.121951219512195
        24 0.123011664899258
        24 0.12407211028632
        24 0.125132555673383
        24 0.126193001060445
        24 0.127253446447508
        25 0.128313891834571
        25 0.129374337221633
        25 0.130434782608696
        25 0.131495227995758
        25 0.132555673382821
        25 0.133616118769883
        25 0.134676564156946
        25 0.135737009544008
        25 0.136797454931071
        25 0.137857900318134
        25 0.138918345705196
        25 0.139978791092259
        25 0.141039236479321
        25 0.142099681866384
        25 0.143160127253446
        25 0.144220572640509
        26 0.145281018027572
        26 0.146341463414634
        26 0.147401908801697
        26 0.148462354188759
        26 0.149522799575822
        26 0.150583244962884
        26 0.151643690349947
        26 0.15270413573701
        26 0.153764581124072
        26 0.154825026511135
        26 0.155885471898197
        26 0.15694591728526
        26 0.158006362672322
        26 0.159066808059385
        26 0.160127253446448
        26 0.16118769883351
        26 0.162248144220573
        26 0.163308589607635
        26 0.164369034994698
        27 0.16542948038176
        27 0.166489925768823
        27 0.167550371155885
        27 0.168610816542948
        27 0.169671261930011
        27 0.170731707317073
        27 0.171792152704136
        27 0.172852598091198
        27 0.173913043478261
        27 0.174973488865323
        27 0.176033934252386
        27 0.177094379639449
        27 0.178154825026511
        27 0.179215270413574
        27 0.180275715800636
        27 0.181336161187699
        28 0.182396606574761
        28 0.183457051961824
        28 0.184517497348887
        28 0.185577942735949
        28 0.186638388123012
        28 0.187698833510074
        28 0.188759278897137
        28 0.189819724284199
        28 0.190880169671262
        28 0.191940615058324
        28 0.193001060445387
        28 0.19406150583245
        28 0.195121951219512
        28 0.196182396606575
        28 0.197242841993637
        29 0.1983032873807
        29 0.199363732767762
        29 0.200424178154825
        29 0.201484623541888
        29 0.20254506892895
        29 0.203605514316013
        29 0.204665959703075
        29 0.205726405090138
        29 0.2067868504772
        29 0.207847295864263
        29 0.208907741251326
        29 0.209968186638388
        30 0.211028632025451
        30 0.212089077412513
        30 0.213149522799576
        30 0.214209968186638
        30 0.215270413573701
        30 0.216330858960764
        30 0.217391304347826
        30 0.218451749734889
        30 0.219512195121951
        30 0.220572640509014
        30 0.221633085896076
        30 0.222693531283139
        30 0.223753976670201
        30 0.224814422057264
        31 0.225874867444327
        31 0.226935312831389
        31 0.227995758218452
        31 0.229056203605514
        31 0.230116648992577
        31 0.231177094379639
        31 0.232237539766702
        31 0.233297985153765
        32 0.234358430540827
        32 0.23541887592789
        32 0.236479321314952
        32 0.237539766702015
        32 0.238600212089077
        32 0.23966065747614
        32 0.240721102863203
        32 0.241781548250265
        32 0.242841993637328
        33 0.24390243902439
        33 0.244962884411453
        33 0.246023329798515
        33 0.247083775185578
        33 0.248144220572641
        33 0.249204665959703
        33 0.250265111346766
        33 0.251325556733828
        33 0.252386002120891
        33 0.253446447507953
        33 0.254506892895016
        33 0.255567338282078
        33 0.256627783669141
        33 0.257688229056204
        33 0.258748674443266
        33 0.259809119830329
        34 0.260869565217391
        34 0.261930010604454
        34 0.262990455991516
        34 0.264050901378579
        34 0.265111346765642
        34 0.266171792152704
        34 0.267232237539767
        34 0.268292682926829
        35 0.269353128313892
        35 0.270413573700954
        35 0.271474019088017
        35 0.27253446447508
        35 0.273594909862142
        35 0.274655355249205
        35 0.275715800636267
        35 0.27677624602333
        35 0.277836691410392
        35 0.278897136797455
        35 0.279957582184517
        36 0.28101802757158
        36 0.282078472958643
        36 0.283138918345705
        36 0.284199363732768
        36 0.28525980911983
        36 0.286320254506893
        36 0.287380699893955
        36 0.288441145281018
        37 0.289501590668081
        37 0.290562036055143
        37 0.291622481442206
        37 0.292682926829268
        37 0.293743372216331
        37 0.294803817603393
        37 0.295864262990456
        37 0.296924708377519
        38 0.297985153764581
        38 0.299045599151644
        38 0.300106044538706
        38 0.301166489925769
        38 0.302226935312831
        38 0.303287380699894
        38 0.304347826086957
        38 0.305408271474019
        38 0.306468716861082
        39 0.307529162248144
        39 0.308589607635207
        39 0.309650053022269
        39 0.310710498409332
        39 0.311770943796394
        39 0.312831389183457
        39 0.31389183457052
        39 0.314952279957582
        40 0.316012725344645
        40 0.317073170731707
        40 0.31813361611877
        40 0.319194061505832
        40 0.320254506892895
        40 0.321314952279958
        40 0.32237539766702
        41 0.323435843054083
        41 0.324496288441145
        41 0.325556733828208
        41 0.32661717921527
        41 0.327677624602333
        41 0.328738069989396
        41 0.329798515376458
        41 0.330858960763521
        42 0.331919406150583
        42 0.332979851537646
        42 0.334040296924708
        42 0.335100742311771
        42 0.336161187698834
        42 0.337221633085896
        42 0.338282078472959
        42 0.339342523860021
        43 0.340402969247084
        43 0.341463414634146
        43 0.342523860021209
        43 0.343584305408271
        43 0.344644750795334
        43 0.345705196182397
        43 0.346765641569459
        43 0.347826086956522
        43 0.348886532343584
        43 0.349946977730647
        44 0.351007423117709
        44 0.352067868504772
        44 0.353128313891835
        44 0.354188759278897
        44 0.35524920466596
        44 0.356309650053022
        44 0.357370095440085
        44 0.358430540827147
        45 0.35949098621421
        45 0.360551431601273
        45 0.361611876988335
        45 0.362672322375398
        45 0.36373276776246
        46 0.364793213149523
        46 0.365853658536585
        46 0.366914103923648
        46 0.36797454931071
        46 0.369034994697773
        46 0.370095440084836
        46 0.371155885471898
        47 0.372216330858961
        47 0.373276776246023
        47 0.374337221633086
        47 0.375397667020148
        47 0.376458112407211
        47 0.377518557794274
        47 0.378579003181336
        47 0.379639448568399
        47 0.380699893955461
        47 0.381760339342524
        47 0.382820784729586
        47 0.383881230116649
        48 0.384941675503712
        48 0.386002120890774
        48 0.387062566277837
        48 0.388123011664899
        48 0.389183457051962
        48 0.390243902439024
        49 0.391304347826087
        49 0.39236479321315
        49 0.393425238600212
        49 0.394485683987275
        49 0.395546129374337
        49 0.3966065747614
        50 0.397667020148462
        50 0.398727465535525
        50 0.399787910922587
        50 0.40084835630965
        50 0.401908801696713
        51 0.402969247083775
        51 0.404029692470838
        51 0.4050901378579
        51 0.406150583244963
        51 0.407211028632025
        51 0.408271474019088
        51 0.409331919406151
        51 0.410392364793213
        51 0.411452810180276
        51 0.412513255567338
        51 0.413573700954401
        51 0.414634146341463
        52 0.415694591728526
        52 0.416755037115589
        52 0.417815482502651
        53 0.418875927889714
        53 0.419936373276776
        53 0.420996818663839
        53 0.422057264050901
        53 0.423117709437964
        53 0.424178154825027
        53 0.425238600212089
        53 0.426299045599152
        53 0.427359490986214
        54 0.428419936373277
        54 0.429480381760339
        54 0.430540827147402
        54 0.431601272534464
        54 0.432661717921527
        54 0.43372216330859
        55 0.434782608695652
        55 0.435843054082715
        55 0.436903499469777
        55 0.43796394485684
        55 0.439024390243902
        55 0.440084835630965
        56 0.441145281018028
        56 0.44220572640509
        56 0.443266171792153
        56 0.444326617179215
        56 0.445387062566278
        56 0.44644750795334
        57 0.447507953340403
        57 0.448568398727466
        57 0.449628844114528
        136 0.863852556480381
        137 0.864447086801427
        137 0.865041617122473
        137 0.86563614744352
        137 0.866230677764566
        137 0.866825208085612
        137 0.867419738406659
        137 0.868014268727705
        138 0.868608799048751
        138 0.869203329369798
        142 0.869797859690844
        143 0.870392390011891
        143 0.870986920332937
        143 0.871581450653983
        145 0.87217598097503
        145 0.872770511296076
        146 0.873365041617122
        147 0.873959571938169
        147 0.874554102259215
        148 0.875148632580262
        148 0.875743162901308
        148 0.876337693222354
        148 0.876932223543401
        149 0.877526753864447
        149 0.878121284185494
        149 0.87871581450654
        150 0.879310344827586
        150 0.879904875148633
        151 0.880499405469679
        151 0.881093935790725
        151 0.881688466111772
        152 0.882282996432818
        153 0.882877526753864
        153 0.883472057074911
        154 0.884066587395957
        155 0.884661117717004
        156 0.88525564803805
        157 0.885850178359096
        157 0.886444708680143
        157 0.887039239001189
        158 0.887633769322235
        158 0.888228299643282
        160 0.888822829964328
        160 0.889417360285375
        160 0.890011890606421
        161 0.890606420927467
        162 0.891200951248514
        162 0.89179548156956
        162 0.892390011890606
        162 0.892984542211653
        162 0.893579072532699
        163 0.894173602853746
        164 0.894768133174792
        164 0.895362663495838
        164 0.895957193816885
        165 0.896551724137931
        166 0.897146254458977
        168 0.897740784780024
        168 0.89833531510107
        169 0.898929845422117
        169 0.899524375743163
        169 0.900118906064209
        170 0.900713436385256
        170 0.901307966706302
        170 0.901902497027348
        170 0.902497027348395
        171 0.903091557669441
        171 0.903686087990488
        171 0.904280618311534
        171 0.90487514863258
        171 0.905469678953627
        171 0.906064209274673
        172 0.906658739595719
        172 0.907253269916766
        173 0.907847800237812
        174 0.908442330558858
        174 0.909036860879905
        174 0.909631391200951
        175 0.910225921521998
        175 0.910820451843044
        175 0.91141498216409
        176 0.912009512485137
        176 0.912604042806183
        177 0.91319857312723
        178 0.913793103448276
        178 0.914387633769322
        179 0.914982164090369
        179 0.915576694411415
        179 0.916171224732461
        180 0.916765755053508
        180 0.917360285374554
        180 0.9179548156956
        182 0.918549346016647
        182 0.919143876337693
        183 0.91973840665874
        184 0.920332936979786
        185 0.920927467300832
        187 0.921521997621879
        188 0.922116527942925
        189 0.922711058263971
        190 0.923305588585018
        191 0.923900118906064
        192 0.924494649227111
        193 0.925089179548157
        194 0.925683709869203
        194 0.92627824019025
        195 0.926872770511296
        197 0.927467300832342
        198 0.928061831153389
        198 0.928656361474435
        199 0.929250891795482
        200 0.929845422116528
        201 0.930439952437574
        201 0.931034482758621
        202 0.931629013079667
        206 0.932223543400713
        206 0.93281807372176
        206 0.933412604042806
        208 0.934007134363853
        208 0.934601664684899
        209 0.935196195005945
        209 0.935790725326992
        209 0.936385255648038
        211 0.936979785969084
        212 0.937574316290131
        213 0.938168846611177
        215 0.938763376932224
        216 0.93935790725327
        217 0.939952437574316
        218 0.940546967895363
        219 0.941141498216409
        219 0.941736028537455
        219 0.942330558858502
        219 0.942925089179548
        220 0.943519619500594
        220 0.944114149821641
        221 0.944708680142687
        221 0.945303210463734
        221 0.94589774078478
        222 0.946492271105826
        223 0.947086801426873
        226 0.947681331747919
        227 0.948275862068966
        227 0.948870392390012
        230 0.949464922711058
        230 0.950059453032105
        231 0.950653983353151
        232 0.951248513674197
        236 0.951843043995244
        239 0.95243757431629
        239 0.953032104637336
        240 0.953626634958383
        240 0.954221165279429
        241 0.954815695600476
        243 0.955410225921522
        243 0.956004756242568
        244 0.956599286563615
        244 0.957193816884661
        246 0.957788347205707
        247 0.958382877526754
        250 0.9589774078478
        251 0.959571938168847
        251 0.960166468489893
        251 0.960760998810939
        251 0.961355529131986
        254 0.961950059453032
        255 0.962544589774079
        256 0.963139120095125
        256 0.963733650416171
        259 0.964328180737218
        259 0.964922711058264
        261 0.96551724137931
        264 0.966111771700357
        267 0.966706302021403
        267 0.967300832342449
        268 0.967895362663496
        272 0.968489892984542
        275 0.969084423305589
        276 0.969678953626635
        276 0.970273483947681
        280 0.970868014268728
        280 0.971462544589774
        283 0.97205707491082
        284 0.972651605231867
        290 0.973246135552913
        291 0.97384066587396
        293 0.974435196195006
        293 0.975029726516052
        293 0.975624256837099
        295 0.976218787158145
        295 0.976813317479191
        297 0.977407847800238
        297 0.978002378121284
        298 0.978596908442331
        298 0.979191438763377
        299 0.979785969084423
        300 0.98038049940547
        301 0.980975029726516
        303 0.981569560047562
        315 0.982164090368609
        316 0.982758620689655
        316 0.983353151010702
        321 0.983947681331748
        324 0.984542211652794
        326 0.985136741973841
        331 0.985731272294887
        336 0.986325802615933
        344 0.98692033293698
        350 0.987514863258026
        350 0.988109393579073
        365 0.988703923900119
        367 0.989298454221165
        378 0.989892984542212
        384 0.990487514863258
        390 0.991082045184304
        392 0.991676575505351
        394 0.992271105826397
        413 0.992865636147443
        420 0.99346016646849
        429 0.994054696789536
        431 0.994649227110583
        452 0.995243757431629
        478 0.995838287752675
        481 0.996432818073722
        485 0.997027348394768
        507 0.997621878715815
        508 0.998216409036861
        509 0.998810939357907
        583 0.999405469678954
    };
    \addlegendentry{Movies}
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]